# Best way to do a "not None" test in Python for a normal and Unicode empty string?

Tags: python, string

In Python 2.7, I'm writing a class that calls a function in an API which might, or might not, return an empty string. Furthermore, the empty string might be unicode `u""`, or non-unicode `""`. I was wondering what the best way to check for this?

The following code works great for an empty string, but not an empty unicode string:

```
class FooClass():
    string = ...
    string = might_return_normal_empty_string_or_unicode_empty_string(string)

    # Works for normal empty strings, not unicode:
    if string is not None:
        print "string is not an empty string."
```

Instead I'd have to write it like this to get it to work for unicode:

```
class BarClass():
    string = ...
    string = might_return_normal_empty_string_or_unicode_empty_string(string)

    # Works for unicode empty strings, not normal:
    if string is not u"":
        print "string is not an empty string."
```

...and like this to get it to work for both empty strings in non-unicode and unicode:

```
class FooBarClass():
    string = ...
    string = might_return_normal_empty_string_or_unicode_empty_string(string)

    # Works for both normal and unicode empty strings:
    if string is not u"" or None:
        print "string is not an empty string."
```

Is the third method the best way to do this, or is there a better way? I ask because writing a `u""` feels a little too hard-coded to me. But if that's the best way to do it, so be it. :) Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: So what sort of not-empty-string things will it return?

Comment: It'll return either `""`, `u""`, or `"some non-empty string"`.

Comment: Your first code checks for None which is not the same thing as an empty string. Which one is being returned?

Comment: I'll guess it never returns anything but a unicode string, and the check always passed right now.

Comment: Confusion reigns supreme. State your expected outcomes for these values: None, "", u"", "a", u"a", 0, 42. Expected outcome should be one of true, false, True, False, exception (which one?).

Comment: If string in [None, '', u'']: print "None or empty string"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Empty strings are considered false.

```
if string:
    # String is not empty.
else:
    # String is empty.
```

Comment: Thanks Artur, I tested it with a None string and discovered that it matches the else clause. So your test checks both if the string is None and if it's empty.

Comment: @bluish Yes, both None and empty sequences (strings, lists, tuples etc.) are considered false. [5.1. Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: So if I want to check to see if a string is not `None`, but *empty*, would I use: `if string: if not string`?

Answer (score 6):

You *never* want to use `is` with anything that isn't guaranteed to be a singleton. Check the length of the returned value, and if it's an instance of `unicode`.

Answer (score 5):

I have to challenge your first statement;

```
# Works for normal empty strings     <-- WRONG
if string is not None:
    print "string is not an empty string."
```

In Python 2.7.1, `"" is not None` evaluates to `True` - so `string=""` results in `string is not an empty string` (which it certainly is!).

Why bring `None` into it at all?

```
s = random_test_string()
s = API_call(s)

if len(s):
    # string is not empty
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Check *what* ?

```
if s is None:
    print "s is None"
else:
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        print "s is unicode, %r" % s
    else:
        print "s is bytes, %r" % s

    if s:
        print "s is not empty"
    else:
        print "s is empty"
```

Just check for `None` first, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is certainly a good thing to include in the conversation, ***especially*** if you're writing a class that can be used by other programmers.

`None` is a valid, and wholly *unique*, value a string can have.

I'm *new* to Python so I'm not yet fully versed in the '*correct*' usage of `None`. *My* most frequent use of it is in initialization of strings and lists. If my code ever hits a case where I'm trying to do something with a string or list that my code has not specifically set to a value, I want to know about it. I'm using it as safety net of sorts.

```
if my_string is '': print('My string is NULL')
elif my_string is None : print('My string.... isn\'t')
else: print('My string is ' + my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python3.8
string = ' '
if string:
    print("Hello World from first statement")
    #this will be print the above line

if string and string.strip():
    print('This will not print anything')

string = None
if string:
    print("will not print anything")

string = ''
if string:
    print("still will not print anything")

first_string = ' '
second_string = ''
if first_string and second_string:
    print('will not print anything')
```